# React-Native Libraries: how to know which to add after cloning a git-project

Tags: git, react-native, dependencies, libraries

How can I know which libraries to install when cloning a React Native project from Git?
When I clone a project, InteliJ does a 'npm install' but not all the libraries used in the React Native project are installed, how can I quickly find out which ones were used and maybe also how to install them?
(I thought I should be able to see this in package.json but in the last project I could not find any libraries that should be installed, like eg React Navigation)
Thanks for replying or referring me to the right documentation.

Comment: Please, provide more details about the project that you're trying to run and his package.json file. if you see some error specify too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every library using on a React Native Project must be specified in the package.json file, more specifically on "dependencies or "devDependencies".

> Dependencies are specified in a simple object that maps a package name to a version range. The version range is a string which has one or more space-separated descriptors. Dependencies can also be identified with a tarball or git URL

If there is some lib using in project that is not specified, it's **wrong**.

Comment: So as I mentioned, I did check the package.json, and did not expect it to be wrong, so the problem was within the cloned project, thanks